# Flatten list of lists in Python with non-iterable types?

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools, flatten, chain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python)

I've seen quite a few 'How to flatten list of lists' questions on SO, but I'm still having trouble with my problem. I have a list of lists with non-iterable types, such as NumPy float64 objects and integers. My basic data structure looks like this:

```
values = ['ER12345', 'AB19991', [[7, 140], [1521, 52372]], 1.7216305062458908, 0.20191695718623365]
```

I've been trying to flatten my list like this:

```
from itertools import chain

format_calcs = list(chain(*values))
```

This code throws a `Type Error` that the float64 and integers are not iterable. How can I flatten a list with non-iterable data types? My desired output is:

```
values = ['ER12345', 'AB19991', 7, 140, 1521, 52372, 1.7216305062458908, 0.20191695718623365]
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I guess you missed this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python/2158532#2158532

Comment: How did you get this list? Not knowing your data's structure a priori and relying on its type is a sign of a suboptimal, non-idiomatic design in Python.

Comment: @zeekay, thanks for the link. i did see this example, but i was attempting to use chain if possible.

Comment: @Mike The `values` list comes from a series of calculations. Some of the numbers are from Python's `Counter()` function, others are from SciPy's Fisher-exact test. Thanks.